# Recognise date year input in system speech recogniser

Tags: speech-recognition

I am trying to recognize year input using system speech. Currently, my code includes number from 0 to 9 in the Grammar so users need to say 'two zero one eight' to input year '2018'.

Could anyone give hints so the recogniser can recognise when users say 'two thousand eighteen'?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should post the source code for the grammar you have created. It is easier for people to give you answers if they can see what you have already tried. Are you using SRGS grammars or the System Speech APIs?

Second, there really is no magic answer to this. You build the grammar to check for what people may say. You have to think out the words and phrases that might be said and create grammar rules to handle that input.

There are some examples you may find helpful if you dig around the internet. Here are some links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/lync-2010/hh538495(v%3Doffice.14)
- https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-grammar/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/speech-technologies/ee800148(v=msdn.10)